# Configuring ActionCable with Elasticache for Rails 5.0 App on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I have created a Rails 5.0 app with Elastic Beanstalk on Amazon Web Services and I have been able to successfully create the website with a functioning database. The only problem is that I need ActionCable for my app to work and it is really hard for me to configure Elasticache and have the rails app successfully communicate to the Elasticache cluster.

A lot of people have told me that the load balancer in Elastic Beanstalk doesn't allow any communication to the the Elasticache cluster and I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to integrate Redis into Elastic Beanstalk in order to properly configure ActionCable.

Do you guys knows a step by step detailed approach to successfully set up ActionCable on Elastic Beanstalk Rails 5.0 app using Elasticache?

Comment: Have you been able to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Most important thing is to change the loadbalancer to user TCP and SSL instead of HTTP and HTTPS. You also need to configure nginx to pass on the upgrade headers on the /cable location.

Try adding this file (nginx.config) in your .ebextensions folder:

```
files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:
    content: |
      client_max_body_size 500M;
      server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;

      upstream backend {
        server unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock;
      }

      server {
        listen 80;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        server_name *.cmgresearch.net;

        large_client_header_buffers 8 32k;

        location / {
          proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
          proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
          proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

          proxy_buffers 8 32k;
          proxy_buffer_size 64k;

          proxy_pass http://backend;
          proxy_redirect off;

          location /assets {
            root /var/app/current/public;
          }

          # enables WS support
          location /cable {
            proxy_pass http://backend;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade "websocket";
            proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          }
        }
      }


container_commands:
  01restart_nginx:
    command: "service nginx restart"
```

See https://blog.cmgresearch.com/2017/05/11/step-7-action-cable-on-elastic-beanstalk.html